# Facebook login dialog blank white screen with close button in my Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am facing Facebook Login Dialog Blank screen with close button

[image]

Comment: Show us your code that could help.

Comment: I request `MainActivity.java`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Strings.xml`.

Comment: Sandbox Mode issue.......

Answer (score 5):

check inside app setting inside facebook that "sandbox" isnt check . if it does it will do this problem . sandbox prevent login from other than the develepor facebook.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, your app wants you to login by:

- either redirecting you to the Facebook App if the latest is installed,
- or to this actual screen (which shouldn't be blank) if you don't have the Facebook App.

My first guess is that your app can't access to the Internet. Can you make sure you've got this line in your Manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[image: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>]

Can you make sure that you successfully entered the Native Android App information in your app settings:

[image: Native Android App]

Moreover, did you:

- set `<string name="app_id">41234567890</string>` in your `res/values/strings.xml`,
- and `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Could you also check that you followed each step of this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).